# How to use radius client

Tags: go, freeradius, radius

Is there an efficient way or a library that does RADIUS CoA (Change of Authorization) using Go?

Note, here I am a client, not a server, is a feature that allows a RADIUS server to set up an active client session

Usage example freeradius

```
echo User-Name=00:00:00:00:00,Framed-IP-Address=127.0.0.1,Session-Timeout=3 | radclient -x 192.168.1.1:4040 coa mysecret 2>&1
```